# Hibernate Validator. How to work with @Valid annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

What purpose of `@Valid` annotation when putting it on method parameter level?

```
public void (@Valid Person p) { ... }
```

I created a test, and passed to this method non-valid object, but nothing happens.
I expect to get an exception.

Comment: How are you instantiating your object? `new` won't trigger the call to the validator, it needs to be triggered by a container (web container, Java EE container etc ...).

Comment: @Perception I included all Hibernate-validator JAR's in classpath, so I think it should work. OR no ?

Comment: I've included some details in my answer below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The @`Valid` annotation on an object is an indication to the validation framework to process the annotated object. When used on a parameter of a method this is referred to as ***method level validation***. Note that method level validation is ***not*** part of the core specification, and in fact is only supported when Bean Validation is integrated into a container type framework (JSF, CDI, Java EE). When Bean Validation is integrated into such a supporting container, what happens is that, as lifecycle methods are called on the bean, the container detects JSR 303 annotations on the methods parameters and triggers validation of the associated bean.

So for example, if you had the following method definition in a JAX-RS resource class:

```
@Path("/example")
public class MyExampleResourceImpl {

    @POST
    @Path("/")
    public Response postExample(@Valid final Example example) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

When the `postExample` method is called in response to a request being handled by the JAX-RS container, the `example` bean will be validated. Contrast this behavior with what would happen if you were running a standalone Java SE app:

```
public class MyMainClass {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final MyMainClass clazz = new MyMainClass();
        clazz.echo(new Example());
    }

    public Example echo(@Valid final Example example) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In this case, running the program will ***not*** trigger validation of the `Example` parameter, even if you included all the JSR 303 runtime JARs. This is because there is no container available that implements method level validation. The [Bean Validation Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/bean_validation-1_0-final-spec.pdf) describes all this in some detail in Appendix C. I've quoted some of it below for your benefit:

> ***Proposal for method-level validation***
>
> This proposition has not been integrated into the core specification
>   and is not part of it. It remains here for archaeological purposes and
>   will be seriously considered for a future revision of this
>   specification. This proposal is likely to be a bit out of sync with
>   the rest of the specification artifacts.
>
> Note: *Bean Validation providers are free to implement this proposal as
>   a specific extension. Such specific extension could for example be accessed
>   via the use of the Validator.unwrap method.*
>
> A popular demand was to provide a method and parameter level validation
>   mechanism reusing the constraint descriptions of the specification. This
>   set of APIs is meant to be used by interceptor frameworks such as:
>
> - application frameworks like
>
>   - JSR-299
> - component frameworks like Enterprise Java Beans
> - aspect based frameworks
>
> These frameworks can call the validation APIs to
>   validate either the parameter list or the returned value of a method
>   when such method is called. More precisely, validation occurs around a
>   method invocation. This extension of the Bean Validation API allows to
>   reuse the core engine as well as the constraint definition and
>   declaration for such method level validations.

Comment: Hibernate Validator has provider-specific support method validation based on the appendix since release 4.2. Note that method validation will be part of the Bean Validation spec as of [revision 1.1](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/1.1.0.beta2/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-methodlevelconstraints).

Comment: `In this case, running the program will not trigger validation of the Example parameter,` --- I'm using Java EE 5, so it mean I can't use @Valid annotations even on container type frameworks? For example on EJB 3.0 methods? I think so because JSR 303 isn't part of Java EE 5. If it right, so I need to manually create `Validator` object and manually validate my method parameters? Thanks

Comment: Yes, unfortunately JSR 303 is integrated with JEE5. You would need to create your Validator via the factory, then validate each bean separately.

Answer (score 1):

Its purpose is to validate the object against the defined constraints.

From [**Hibernate Docs**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validate)

> Performs validation recursively on the associated object. If the
>   object is a collection or an array, the elements are validated
>   recursively. If the object is a map, the value elements are validated
>   recursively.

This might help http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/